# why isn't "そなわち" in dictionaries? what does it mean?

Tags: set-phrases

I am pretty sure that I have heard the phrase "そなわち" used to begin sentences. Googling "そなわち" returns about 35,000 pages. Just like I remember, most use "そなわち" as a phrase at the beginning of a sentence. However, neither [goo dict](http://www.goo.ne.jp/) or [jisho dict](http://jisho.org/) have this phrase.

- what does "そなわち" mean?
- Why isn't "そなわち" in either of those dictionaries?
- Goo and Jisho are probably weak dictionaries. What are the jp/jp, eng/jp, jp/eng dictionaries that the moderators use?

Comment: Moderators are just people who try to help the site function the way it's supposed to.  Although I have a ♦ diamond next to my name (indicating that I'm a moderator), there are other users on the site who are more knowledgeable than me but don't have ♦ diamonds :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **す**なわち and should be in every dictionary.  It means "therefore"/"namely".

Comment: yep. I need to work on my listening skills.

Comment: Some people do say そなわち in real life, so maybe that is actually what you heard.  The dictionary spelling is すなわち, though.